Turn table into a list
I have this table of what people are missing on each month, and what are they missing(maked as missing) or they have(marked with an "X") or if the guy wasn't working at that time, it says not working.
This is the table layout
Table Layout
I want to turn that into a list with all the missing months of each thing so it can look maybe like this
Year 2023
Worker1_name
NÒMINA:(Months missing here)
REGISTRE DE JORNADA:(Months missing here)

Year 2023
Worker2_name
...

And so on so forth, I don't know if this is possible though.



Month
AGUILERA AVILA, RAFAEL
ANGUITA MARTIN, MARTA
AUMEDES SANCHEZ, JOSEP Mª
GINESTÀ ALVAREZ DE LARA, Mª.DOLORES
GRIMAL RIBOT, LLUIS
HERNANDEZ FUENTES, DOLORES
ILLA FONT, ADRIÀ
LOPEZ GUERRERO, ALEXIS
LOPEZ RUIZ, JAVIER
MARTINEZ RECHE, JOAQUIN
NUÑEZ HIDALGO, LUIS
RUIZ FERNANDO, MIREIA
SANCHEZ RIO-VALLE, MANUEL DIEGO
TAMBADOU, YUSUPHA
VALENZUELA MONTORE, JESUS
VERA VICO, JOSE
VERDUGUEZ ENCINAS, VICTOR RONALD
WAGGEH SAWANEH, MOHAMED KISSIMA




JAN NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
Not working
X
Missing
X
X
X


JAN REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
Missing
Missing
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
X
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


FEB NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
Not working
X
Missing
X
X
X


FEB REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
Missing
Missing
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
X
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


MAR NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
Not working
X
Missing
X
X
X


MAR REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
X
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


APR NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
Not working
X
Missing
X
X
X


APR REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
X
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


MAY NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
Not working
X
Missing
X
X
X


MAY REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
X
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


JUN NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
X
X


JUN REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
X
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


JUL NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
X
X


JUL REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


AUG NÒMINA
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
X
Missing
Not working
X
Missing
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


AUG REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


SEP NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
Missing
X
Not working
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
X
X



SEP REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


OCT NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
Missing
X
Not working
X
X
X
X
X



OCT REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


NOV NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
X
X


NOV REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing


DEC NÒMINA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
X
Not working
X
X
X
X
X


DEC REGISTRE DE JORNADA
Missing
X
X
X
X
X
Missing
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
X
Not working
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing
Missing




Isn't this just a vlookup function?

@Wimanicesir I'm still learing so Idk what that is yet hahaha

Here is a rundown of VLOOKUP, and other similar functions

It wouldn't be a vlookup because OP is asking presumably for all the month's the worker was missing in a table. This would be a filter function based on the worker name and textjoin into one cell I imagine

If it is not too much trouble, could you please post the data as markdown table?

@nkalvi done(i think)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers | btw, after the OP edit the question seems much more approachable. nice edits.

Here's a quick attempt; I'm not sure how to get the years, so I have used a fixed string. This requires Microsoft 365. You can check the steps by changing result to months, register etc. Please look up the references for LET, LAMBDA etc. from here: LET function - Microsoft Support
Enter the following in the first cell for the results:
=LET(
    header, A3:T3,
    payroll_data, A4:T26,
    comment_1, "Take first row, drop the first column when needed",
    employee_names, DROP(header, , 1),
    months, TEXTBEFORE(CHOOSECOLS(payroll_data, 1), " "),
    register, TEXTAFTER(CHOOSECOLS(payroll_data, 1), " "),
    result, REDUCE(
        "Missing months for employees",
        DROP(employee_names, , 1),
        LAMBDA(list, name,
            LET(
                is_missing, CHOOSECOLS(payroll_data, XMATCH(name, employee_names)) =
                    "Missing",
                missing_months, LAMBDA(name, for_register,
                    for_register & ": " &
                        ARRAYTOTEXT(
                            FILTER(months, (register = for_register) * is_missing, "--")
                        )
                ),
                VSTACK(
                    list,
                    VSTACK(
                        "Year 2023",
                        name,
                        missing_months(name, "NÒMINA"),
                        missing_months(name, "REGISTRE DE JORNADA"),
                        ""
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    result
)



Alternatively you can use this formula which returns the same result in my sheet:
=REDUCE("Missing months for employees",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B1:S1)),
LAMBDA(u,v,VSTACK(u,VSTACK("Year 2023",INDEX(B1:S1,,v),
IFERROR("NÒMINA : "&TEXTJOIN(" ",,TEXTBEFORE(FILTER(A2:A25, 
(CHOOSECOLS(B2:S25,v)="Missing")*
(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("NÒMINA",A2:A25))))," ")),"NÒMINA : "),
IFERROR("REGISTRE DE JORNADA : "&TEXTJOIN(" ",,TEXTBEFORE(FILTER(A2:A25, 
(CHOOSECOLS(B2:S25,v)="Missing")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("REGISTRE DE 
JORNADA",A2:A25))))," ")),"REGISTRE DE JORNADA :"),""))))



When copied to my sheet, it didn't show up the missing months of "REGISTRE DE JORNADA" but it got fixed when I tried to make it look better with the spacing and format. It ended up fixing it somehow
